# Using postive verbs to express passive meanings

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

[image]

This book teaches us some example of using postive verbs to express passive meanings.

> The kind of cloth **washes** easily.
>
> These books **sell** well.
>
> The door doesn't **lock**.
>
> This pen **writes** very well.

Then, gives a question of example.

> The hero's story ____ differently in the newspaper.
>
> A. was reported   B. was reporting    C. reports  D. reported

And the given answer is C. Because the time / tense does't be told, so only the "reports" of present tense can be chosen.

Someone argues about this, deems the A is right too.

What do you think about this?

Comment: If I were writing the sentence, I would choose A).  But using A) is not an example of a passive meaning.  The C) answer is a less common expression, but it is an example of your subject material - it is a verb, with story as the subject, that attributes a quality rather than describes an action that "story" is taking or has taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version A is grammatical but it doesn't correspond to the task of using a *positive* verb in a passive meaning. Along with '**reports**', the word '**reads**' is possible here which would mean '*was written (in different words)*'. A similar example ('*a passage that reads differently in older versions*') can be found in Mirriam-Webster Dictionary. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/read